# I can't login to facebook using an app developed in unity with facebook SDK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I make an android game and I integrated it with Facebook, and it was working fine until I received this notification on my Facebook developer page:

**This account has enhanced targeting data set to off. We are removing the opt out setting, effective October 15. Note that data received through the use of our pixel and mobile app events has not been used for targeting to date, and we do not have plans to do so beyond small-scale tests. If we start using this data to improve ad targeting, we will ensure that this data makes up only a small percentage of the inputs into each targeting segment. You can also remove the Facebook pixel, app events and Social Plugins from your websites and apps before the effective date.**

The game keep loading when I try to login to Facebook then its back to the game scene like if the user cancel the login, and I really can't find a solution since the game is working in Unity editor, the login working only in android phone if I uninstall the Facebook app

Comment: Facing the same issue. Have you got any solution?